# Distributed tensorflow : What is the job of chief worker?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using a version of the distributed tensorflow example https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed
Here is my code in "mnist_trainer.py".

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

# Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")

# Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("hidden_units", 100,
                            "Number of units in the hidden layer of the NN")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "/home/anijsure/mnist_data",
                           "Directory for storing mnist data")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 100, "Training batch size")

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

IMAGE_PIXELS = 28

def main(_):
  print "Starting"
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  print "Cluster starting"
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  print "Server starting"
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    print "Job : WORKER"

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):
      mytask = tf.constant(FLAGS.task_index, name="mytask")

      mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels))
      # Create batches of data
      dataset = dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
      # Create an iterator, to go over the dataset
      iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
      X,Y = iterator.get_next()

      # Variables of the hidden layer
      hid_w = tf.Variable(
          tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS * IMAGE_PIXELS, FLAGS.hidden_units],
                              stddev=1.0 / IMAGE_PIXELS), name="hid_w")
      hid_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([FLAGS.hidden_units]), name="hid_b")

      # Variables of the softmax layer
      sm_w = tf.Variable(
          tf.truncated_normal([FLAGS.hidden_units, 10],
                              stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(FLAGS.hidden_units)),
          name="sm_w")
      sm_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="sm_b")

      hid_lin = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(X, hid_w, hid_b)
      hid = tf.nn.relu(hid_lin)

      y = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(hid, sm_w, sm_b)
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=y), name="loss")

      global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step)


    # The StopAtStepHook handles stopping after running given steps.
    chiefhooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=25)]
    allhooks=[tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors={"Task": "mytask","loss":"loss", "Step":"global_step"}, every_n_iter=1)]

    # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
    # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
    # or an error occurs.
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                           checkpoint_dir="/tmp/train_logs_%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
                                           hooks=allhooks, chief_only_hooks=chiefhooks) as mon_sess:
      mon_sess.run(iterator.initializer)
      while not mon_sess.should_stop():
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.
        # mon_sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.

        _ = mon_sess.run([train_op])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

I run it like so:

```
HOSTS=<node0>:2222
WORKERS=<node1>:2222,<node1>:2223,<node1>:2224

python mnist_trainer.py --ps_hosts=$HOSTS --worker_hosts=$WORKERS --job_name=ps --task_index=0 &
python mnist_trainer.py --data_dir mnist_data --ps_hosts=$HOSTS --worker_hosts=$WORKERS --job_name=worker --task_index=0 2>&1 | tee worker0.log &
python mnist_trainer.py --data_dir mnist_data_1 --ps_hosts=$HOSTS --worker_hosts=$WORKERS --job_name=worker --task_index=1 2>&1 | tee worker1.log &
python mnist_trainer.py --data_dir mnist_data_2 --ps_hosts=$HOSTS --worker_hosts=$WORKERS --job_name=worker --task_index=2 2>&1 | tee worker2.log &
```

I have tried this with 1 PS and 2 or 3 workers - both nodes are CPU machines. PS is on node0 and workers are all different ports on node1. In either of 2 or 3 worker case, chief worker (task0 worker) does not seem to be making any updates at all. I have set the StopatStepHook to 25 on chief worker only. However training seems to stop at global_step=549 with 2 worker case and global_step=1098 with 3 worker case. I am printing worker task# with the LoggingTensorHook and it only shows task 1 and 2 logging anything. Only on the last iteration does task 0 log the tensors.

Is this expected behaviour? Is chief worker supposed to only keep track of monitoring session, checkpointing, etc?

Considering that the training does stop at this magic number of 550 iters, something on the chief worker is indeed triggering the stop.

What is the chief worker doing and how is it keeping track of the stopping step?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the chief worker is responsible for `initialize graph`, `save model checkpoint` operations for the training cluster.

Comment: In this example though, all the workers would initialize the graph.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the TensorFlow documentation for `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate):

> …[T]he chief worker also does the model training job, similar to other non-chief training workers (see next paragraph). In addition to the model training, it manages some extra work, e.g., checkpoint saving and restoring, writing summaries, etc.